# Regex to exclude zip code

Tags: regex

I need help to write a regex to exclude zip codes :
I need to exclude all following zip codes :

```
971xx 
972xx 
973xx 
974xx 
975xx 
976xx 
984xx 
986xx 
987xx 
988xx
```

Can you help me writing the correct expression ?
Thanks

Comment: use ngative lookahead (?!971\d+) or smoething like this

Comment: You need to update your question with the regex you tried, some ex of zip codes you want to match and finally you need to specify what the `x` in your zipcode means..

Answer (score 1):

It's seem to me that you want to exclude french DOM-TOM zip code.

How about:

```
\b(?!97[1-6]|98[4678])\d{5}\b
```